# bind method with arguments to backbone model change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I think this question is more a javascript question than a backbone question, but I've run into it while developing an application in backbone, so that's the context I will ask it in.

I am binding a method with arguments to a model's change event. The code below executes that method when the listener is bound, not when the event is fired:

`this.model.on("change:disposition", this.dChange("disposition"), this);`

while the following code executes the method when the change event is fired (the desired behavior):

`this.model.on("change:disposition", function(){ this.dChange("disposition"); }, this);`

I would appreciate it if someone could describe what specifically is happening in these two instances. Also, is there is a better way to bind a method with arguments rather than wrapping it in a closure as I've done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `this.dChange("disposition")` you're invoking the function. (You're using the parentheses `()` to invoke)

But when you do `function() {}` or `this.dChange` you're in fact referencing a function object. And it's this reference that the event manager will call once the event is fired.

*Side note:* In your case, instead of using an anonymus function, you could use the [bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) method of Underscore.js like this:

```
this.model.on("change:disposition", _.bind(this.dChange, this, "disposition"));
```